# Dozer, InstantiationException on custom converter

Tags: mapping, converters, dozer, instantiationexception

I've wrote my own customer converter:

```
public class MyFancyCustomConverter extends DozerConverter<Integer, AnObject>
{
    public MyFancyCustomConverter(Class<Integer> prototypeA, Class<AnObject> prototypeB)
    {
        super(prototypeA, prototypeB);
    }

    @Override
    public AnObject convertTo(Integer source, AnObject destination)
    {
        // TODO: do something
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer convertFrom(AnObject source, Integer destination)
    {
        // TODO: do something
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And my mapping.xml:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>java.lang.Integer</class-a>
    <class-b>xyz.AnObject</class-b>
    <field custom-converter="xyz.MyFancyCustomConverter" custom-converter-param="hello">
      <a>this</a>
      <b key="my.key">this</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

But I get this Exception:

org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.InstantiationException: xyz.MyFancyCustomConverter

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I guess it's because MyFancyCustomConverter doesn't have a default converter. But I can't add one, because DozerConverter doesn't have one...

Comment: please add the full stacktrace

Answer (score 13):

```
public MyFancyCustomConverter(Class<Integer> prototypeA, Class<AnObject> prototypeB)
{
    super(prototypeA, prototypeB);
}
```

Should be

```
public MyFancyCustomConverter()
{
    super(Integer.class, AnObject.class);
}
```

The superclass needs to know the runtime type of the two classes, and because of type erasure, needs a type token to be passed in.